# illustrator brush path to pen path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, pen-tool, brush

I need to convert **brush path to pen path**.

I need the **path** not **the outline of the brush stroke**. So "**expand appearance**" or "**create outline**" is not a solution for me.

This is for a project with VideoScribe (a software that turns SVGs in to drawing animations) which needs contours to be pen paths. But most of the time I get drawings which were made with brush tool from the artists.

So I had to redraw them. Is there a way to convert this?

Comment: Do you mean **blob brush tool** or **paintbrush tool**? Block brush no theres no way. Paintbrush they are normal paths just change the stroke.

Comment: Does clicking the "Basic" option n the brush panel work? It should for any live brush strokes.

Comment: Normal brush... Hoş can i change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to brush panels and click brush icon with slash symbol on it at the bottom of the panel.
Make sure the brush path thaht  you want to change already selected.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that by changing the brush definition to basic.
[image]

It will work with Videoscribe for sure.